# Sequencer won't show the actual animation

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Whenever I have sequencer on under Post Processing only the movie in the video sequence shows up while redering and not the animation. When I turn of sequencer the animation shows up but not the movie in the video sequence. Any advice?

Comment: Is it true you first want to create an image sequence and next to  compose a final movie in the Blender VSE?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a scene to be used in video sequence editor, add a *Scene Strip*.

*Add > Scene*

You can add the current scene as well as other scenes.

[image]

Check the Open GL Preview and choose the Preview Shading
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Create a second scene.  The first scene, has 3D geometry, and has sequencer turned off.  The second scene is new and has no 3D geometry, and has sequencer turned on, and compositor turned off.  This suits many peoples work flow.
- Practice switching scenes. It will become easy.

[image]

- Many people render a 3d scene as a series of images [image sequence] or movie.  Next they combine many image sequences or movies in the Blender VSE.