# How to switch render source (VSE or Camera)?

Tags: rendering, interface, video-sequence-editor

If you create a scene for the Video Sequence Editor and start working on a project Blender will render the output from the VSE. But if you want to later switch it to render your 3D scene again (the camera output) **where is the setting to select the source?**

Usually I keep a separate .blend for VSE edits so I don't need to switch, but I feel like I ought to learn how to do this as it's pretty basic. I would expect to find this in the Render context but I see no place to specify the source.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31751/sequencer-wont-show-the-actual-animation/39221#39221

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there's anything in the sequencer, blender will render from there by default. If you don't want to render from the sequencer even if there are strips, disable *Sequencer* in *Output Properties> Post Processing*:

[image: Screenshot of the proper menu]

Comment: Ah-ha! It *was* in the Render context, hidden in plain view. Thanks!