# Render new stills and not the created video sequence

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

Im new to the video editing side of blender and here's the thing:
i was stitching image sequences of a rendered animation i created and i want to take a step baCK and change something on the animation but when i try to render a new image sequence again, only blender does is output a blank, empty gray screen,
my guess is that this is the video sequence rendering and not the animation, because i moved the image sequence strips away from the frame range, because i want it out of the way when rendering the edited animation but alas, blank

what am i not getting here? how can i get blender to render the animation again? and not the video sequence?

Comment: haha found the devil!

When i entered video sequence mode, the post processing menu put a check on the sequencer and compositing checkbox. this adds the video composition to the render stack on top of the usual animation rendering

or atleast that's how i see it, if anyone wants to add something to clear this i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: To render animation of render layers instead of sequencer / compositor disable them temporarily in Render panel. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39673/how-to-switch-render-source-vse-or-camera

Comment: @MrZak thanks, i already figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though you have not set your render output back to still images.

[image]

If you already have multiple sequences you want to re-stitch, just be sure to re-adjust your start and end frames.

[image]

Comment: thanks! what i did  was i adjusted the frame range from 1-30  [opening part of the animation] and reposition every video strip away [outside] from the range. when i hit render animation, bam! not rendering

Comment: i already fixed it 
although by that time, i did set the setting to PNG

Comment: wait @Ratt , (also new here  in stack exchange) how do you post pictures along with your comments?