# I don't want to render from the Video Sequence Editor

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

As soon as I have a strip in the Video Sequence Editor it renders from that.
How can I choose between rendering from the Video Sequence Editor and rendering the actual Scene?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39673/how-to-switch-render-source-vse-or-camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any kind of strip in the Sequencer and don't want it to be rendered, then:
In the *Properties*' Render panel > *Post processing* > uncheck *Sequencer*